# Java: The input I enter must assign according to its datatype..How?

Tags: java, android

If I give 4 as an input.. the 4 must be assigned to an integer variable.

If I give 4.2 as input... the 4.2 must assign to an float variable.

Answer (score 1):

you should get idea byu below class.

```
class Typetester {
    void byte printType(byte x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an byte");
    }
    void int printType(int x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an int");
    }
    void float printType(float x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an float");
    }
    void double printType(double x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an double");
    }
    void char printType(char x) {
        System.out.println(x + " is an char");
    }
}
```

Comment: I am an amateur in java.. why -1

Answer (score 1):

Try overloading concept

```
int int_val;
float float_val;

public void assignValue(int value){
    int_val = value;
}

public void assignValue(float value){
    float_val = value;
}
```

then use assignValue(4); or assignValue(4.2);